# MySQL Getting the most recent entry from two database tables

Tags: mysql, sql, database

thanks for reading.

I have two tables. A Client Table, and a Note table.

Users have the ability to make separate notes depending the client they select. Each note is it's own distinct entry into the database, tied to a clientID.

Right now I am trying to devise a query which will give me the most recent note and all of the client information.

EDIT: I apologize, I realize I need to clarify this statement because it was ambiguous. *I need the most recent note for each client in the client table*

Right now I can get all of the information I want except for the fact that the note I get is the oldest instead of the newest. all notes also have a noteID that I am trying to use to get the most recent note.

This is the query I am currently using.

```
SELECT c.clientID, count(c.clientID), c.account_name, c.created_date, c.cert_verified, n.noteID, n.note_date, n.note_body 
FROM clients c, notes n 
WHERE c.clientID = n.clientID AND (SELECT max(n.noteID) from notes n) 
GROUP BY c.clientID ASC
```

Any ideas would be very much appreciated. I have found a couple of examples, but none that we extremely applicable.

Thanks!

Comment: `count(c.clientID)` will only ever be 1 in a many to one relationship - each note is about 1 client

Comment: I am using count(c.clientID) to determine how many note records each client has.

So if meouw has 10 note entries in this table, your count will be ten etc....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try something like:

```
SELECT c.clientID, count(c.clientID), c.account_name, c.created_date, c.cert_verified, n.noteID, n.note_date, n.note_body 
FROM clients c, notes n 
WHERE c.clientID = n.clientID AND
  n.noteID in (SELECT max(nm.noteID) from notes nm where nm.clientId = c.clientID) 
GROUP BY c.clientID ASC
```

Cheers,

Chris.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
SELECT c.clientID, count(c.clientID), c.account_name, c.created_date, c.cert_verified, n.noteID, n.note_date, n.note_body 
FROM clients c, notes n 
WHERE c.clientID = n.clientID 
   AND n.noteID = (SELECT max(n2.noteID) from notes n2) 
   AND n.note_date = (SELECT max(n2.note_date) FROM notes n2)
GROUP BY c.clientID ASC
```

Your query does not check to make sure the `noteID` **EQUALS** the max `noteID` from the table. Also, you may have issues naming the alias of your subquery the same thing as the outer query (in your case, the notes table has an alias of `n` in both queries).

Comment: I didn't even think about the outer query and inner query having the same alias. Thanks for pointing that out!

Comment: @mike-brant What was the purpose of adding a single space to the end of my answer?

Comment: this has the same issue as the other answer. It only provides the most recent client and note. I need the most recent note for ALL clients.